# How to correctly report startup issues via ubuntu-bug?

Tags: bug-reporting, launchpad

I would like to report an issue I have at startup (a crackling noise from my speakers, every time I boot), but I don't know how to do it properly.
I tried ubuntu-bug but since startup is not a package, I don't find how to report.
How should I report my bug to ensure that it will worked on?

Comment: When during boot? Immediately after BIOS is done booting, sometime during the splash screen, when the login screen appears, when your desktop appears after logging in?

Comment: During the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the wiki page, "DebuggingSoundProblems"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems), you can report audio bugs by opening a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and running:

```
ubuntu-bug -s audio
```

You might get lucky [looking at similar issues posted online](https://www.google.com/search?q=speakers+pop+boot+ubuntu), some with solutions.

Comment: I tried the audio section of the bug report but my problem doesn't really fit there, it's not a playback issue.  
I'm wondering how one should report any issue happening during startup, at the splash screen for instance. There does not seem to be any section of the bug report for that.  
But ultimately, I might use the audio section, yes.